# Testing constructor when using @Before annotation

Tags: junit, constructor, annotations, mocking

I want to test *SomeClass* methods.

For that, I need *SomeClass* instance in every test so I'm using @Before annotation and initiate an instance of *SomeClass* named *SC*.

**The problem is:-** How can I test the constructor function after I already use it? It doesn't make sense.

**Additional question:-** The constructor can get number of arguments and they can influnce the methods outputs, should I mock this class instead of creating an instance of it?

```
public class SomeClassTest {
        SomeClass SC;

        @Before
        public void initlize() throws IOException{
            SC= new SomeClass (argument1,argument2,..);
        }

        @Test
        public void ConstructorTest() {
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use the object SC in your ConstructorTest. If you wan't to test a certain outcome from the construction of a SomeClass object with certain parameters then just construct it as such within your ConstructorTest and then assert the relevant outcomes you expect on the newly constructed object.

And no you shouldn't be mocking this class. The test is for testing this class so if you mock it's behaviour then you aren't really testing anything.